# Could not build wheels for patchelf, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, dbus

when I was trying to build a news notifier using python.It gave me an error saying dbus is not installed. So I tried to install dbus using `pip3 install dbus-python`.After an eternity later it shoot back an error saying `Could not build wheels for patchelf, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip`

so anyone know the solution ?? and thanks in advance
I am using python 3.11.2

Comment: There should be a different error earlier in the log, please post the whole output